CDC capture job not running after running sys.scan_job manually
I have a CDC enabled table used for replication. One of my stored procedure I have, runs this exec sys.sp_cdc_scan manually for a specific case (my stored procedure is invoked by a DDL trigger which I created). But after running the stored procedure manually I found automatic capture job for CDC is not working. I have to run sys.sp_cdc_scan manually each time to capture the DML changes into my capture instance. I'm not sure why is that happening. Any lead will be helpful.
I'm running Azure SQL database.
The reason for running sys.sp_cdc_scan is to make sure that I get DMLs operations in capture instance as soon as I do any DML operation, in simple terms
begin tran
insert into t1(col1) values(1);
select * from cdc.dbo_t1_CT;
commit tran

I won't get any records in capture instance in the above case, but if I manage to write my transaction like this
begin tran
insert into t1(col1) values(1);
exec sys.sp_cdc_scan;
select * from cdc.dbo_t1_CT;
commit tran

I get the records in capture instance as soon I make a DML operation, which is what I need.

I'm not sure what's happening to you, but can you elaborate on why you feel the need to run anything but the standard CDC capture job? I'm not saying you're wrong in doing so, but I've run CDC in a couple of shops and never had to do that.

Thanks for responding, added my reason in description itself.

CDC is designed to be asynchronous. That is, the log reader job will get your data eventually and not delay the inciting transaction. I would recommend either getting rid of your trigger and letting CDC work as designed or use your trigger to select from the inserted and/or deleted metatables and skip CDC altogether.

Okay so, the issue was whenever a session runs sys.sp_cdc_scan manually, it needs to disconnect itself from server so that automatic scheduling of sys.sp_cdc_scan can work. When I reconnected to my sqlserver instance, the issue got resolved on its own.
SQLServer small CDC tip
When we face error related to CDC, we should query this table sys.dm_cdc_errors first. It gives us crucial information which helps in debugging the issues. I was able to find the root cause of my issue with help of this table itself.
